# wooCommerce how to add featured image in ORDER DETAILS table

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Anyone knows how to customize `wooCommerce` ORDER DETAILS table and add product (featured) image in it?

I tried to use:

```
$img = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $item['product_id'] );
<img src="' . img[0] . '">'
```

In `woocommerce/templates/single-product/order-details.php`
but its not working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

within your order-details.php add the following, I hope this works for you aswell.

```
echo get_the_post_thumbnail( $item['product_id'], 'full' );
```

Answer (score 0):

The order-details.php is in the /wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/templates/order folder. 
You will have to copy it to wp-content/themes/*your-theme*/woocommerce/order folder.

Than add the following line:
echo $thumbnail = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_in_cart_product_thumbnail', $_product->get_image() );

before the lines containing this text:
echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_order_item_name'

Well done!